# Trying to fetch json list of issues from JIRA using jira-connector library in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, jira

As u may see, I am connecting to JIRA using the jira-connector library, I am trying to display the data in JSON format, but I don't get any of the results when i do console.log ( provided an image).

```
const  JiraClient = require('jira-connector');

const  jira = new JiraClient( {
host: 'URL',
basic_auth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
 }
});


jira.search.search(
{
  jql: 'type = bug'
}, 

function(error, issue) 
{
 console.log(issue);
}
);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try logging the error as well; anything come up?

Comment: Yes let me add the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't show your actual config code, based on the error I'm guessing you are passing a string as the `host` key that the module doesn't parse as you expect.

From the examples on the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-connector), they don't pass the protocol just the host name (e.g. `host: 'jira.example.com'` vice `host: 'http://jira.example.com'`.

From the error either you're forgetting the colon after `http` or else they don't accept the protocol and just want the hostname there.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/floralvikings/jira-connector/blob/master/index.js), it looks like they don't try and parse the protocol out of the hostname, and if you want to pass a protocol (e.g. http), that's a different config option.  Try this:

```
const  jira = new JiraClient( {
  host: 'hostname-without-http',
  protocol: 'http', // defaults to https
  basic_auth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  }
});
```

Comment: @bobb1213131 it doesn't look like you've updated the question since my last edit. Check again.

Comment: I had to change the port, the URL without http, the protocol to 'http' as u mentioned

Comment: hey can you take a look at my problem paul!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068278/using-node-js-to-fetch-json-data-from-jira-using-the-jira-connector-library-not