# Using node.js to fetch json data from jira using the jira-connector library not working when deployed in heroku

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

As mentioned above, I fetched data and displayed it in a get request to retrieve data from server and display it in JSON format, I used this library **https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-connector**, whenever i locally fetch data **it works** and displays the JSON data but when I deploy it in Heroku web server (**example.herokuapp.com**), the fetched data is not displayed at
**example.herokuapp.com/jiraWIPCRs** (empty data / null) and in **http://localhost:2000/jiraWIPCRs** the data is displayed.

```
const base64 = require('base-64');
const JiraClient = require('jira-connector');

const jira = new JiraClient( {
host: '***********************',
protocol: 'http',
basic_auth: {
    base64: base64.encode("username:password")
},
port: ****

});

//endpoint
app.get('/jiraWIPCRs', (req, res) =>{

jira.search.search({
    jql: ' "ECR #" != NULL AND "status" != Accepted AND "status" != Canceled AND "type" = "Change Request" AND "project"="Customer Support"',
    maxResults: 5000
}, function(error, issue) {
    res.send(issue);
});

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("App is running on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: Means what it says, it can't find the address (ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com).  Make sure the domain name is correct and registered.

Comment: Yeah i put everything correctly, but it seems to not be working still, but why does it work locally and not in the web server of heroku?

Comment: I tried without luck, could be a network issue?

Comment: Oh.. it doesn't work on your side? Maybe the link is blocked due to company privacy

Comment: Ya.. sorry so everything seems to be working, its the side of my company networking privacy